# api document request/Docking platform

Tags: api, facebook-page, platform, docking

What is the difference between Facebook Shops and Facebook Page Shops? Is this the same API?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/platforms/onboarding/cmredirect#get-catalog-and-page-id-from-cms